# Codename One UWP build - icon size error

Tags: build, uwp, codenameone

I am getting a error when sending an app to the build server to create a UWP build:

```
[exec] (_ValidateAppxPackage target) -> 
[exec]   Package.appxmanifest(19,26): error APPX3207: App manifest references the wide 310x150 logo image 'Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png' which is larger than the maximum image file size. It must be no larger than 204,800 bytes.
```

The app's logo is the required size (512x512) so I am a bit perplexed. Any help would be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: It is kind of wide logo and clearly said must be in 310x150 with maximum 200kb

Comment: Codename One requires the application logo to be 512x512 otherwise the build can't be sent to the server.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the cause. When Codename One resizes the app icon from the provided size of 512x512 to 310x150 it doesn't seem to reduce the file size at all. As my original icon was (just) over 200Kb the smaller version was also over the limit. I have optimised my icon's PNG file and now the build succeeds.